# stdarg.h functionality appears to concatenate arguments wrongly

Tags: c, variadic-functions

**TL;DR: `mprintf("%s and %s", arg1, arg2)` appears to print `"arg1arg2 and arg2"` instead of `"arg1 and arg2"` using `va_*` macros defined in `stdarg.h`**

Hello, all. I'm using the functionality provided by vsprintf like so:

*exits.c*

```
#include "../../utils/printutil.c"

...

char dir[4][5];
char* format;

...

switch(bitcount) {

    ...

    case 2: format = "%s and %s";
        mprintf(format, dir[0], dir[1]);
    break;

    ...
}
```

*Note: `dir` gets its values from `strcpy(dir[bitcount], names[dircount]);`, where `names` is simply a char pointer array such that `dir[0] = "North"`, `dir[1] = "East"`, `dir[2] = South"`, and `dir[3] = "West"`.*

---

*printutil.c*

```
/* Utils file to provide common utilities not tied specifically to any aspect of the software */

#include "printutil.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

char* mprintf(const char * format, ...) {
/* Prints a statement containing a format and then multiple arguments. */

    char *buf;
    va_list args;

    va_start (args, format);
    buf = malloc(sizeof(format) + sizeof(args));
    vsprintf (buf, format, args);
    va_end (args);

    return buf;
}
```

*Note: that `printutil.h` simply contains function prototypes*

---

So that's the structure of the code. During a case of the switch statement, a format string is specified, and then `mprintf()` (defined in printutil.c) is called with the format and the args dir[0] and dir[1], two variables that were successfully written to earlier in exits.c.

Using gdb, I was able to discern that the values being passed to `mprintf()` were as expected:

```
Breakpoint 1, exitstr (exits=5 '\005') at exits.c:33
33          switch(bitcount) {
(gdb) s
38              case 2: format = "%s and %s";
(gdb) s
39                  mprintf(format, dir[0], dir[1]);
(gdb) p format
$1 = 0x403115 "%s and %s"
(gdb) p dir[0]
$2 = "North"
(gdb) p dir[1]
$3 = "South"
```

When I step into the `mprintf()` function, gdb shows the contents of format are exactly as they should be, and shows the content of the `va_list args` as so:

```
17          vsprintf (buf, format, args);
(gdb) p format
$4 = 0x403115 "%s and %s"
(gdb) p args
$5 = {{gp_offset = 8, fp_offset = 48, overflow_arg_area = 0x7fffffffe710,
    reg_save_area = 0x7fffffffe650}}
```

I built this code based on examples found in the cplusplus.com reference for [vprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/vprintf/) and [vsprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/vsprintf/) and they both indicate that I have used the functions and the macros defined in `stdarg.h` correctly.

However, after stepping over the `vsprintf()` line, printing the contents of `buf` yields the source of my problems. Namely that the second argument is seemingly concatenated to the first, and then the second argument is re-used for the second format specifier.

```
(gdb) print buf
$7 = 0x63ca50 "NorthSouth and South"
```

Strangely, this only appears to happen when either 'North' or 'South' are the first arguments. If 'East' or 'West' are the first arguments, the arguments are printed to `buf` correctly.

---

**Thank you all, in advance, for your time and patience.**

Comment: Owen,  the string "North" requires 6 bytes (when the termination '\0' is included.  Perhaps 'char dir[4][5];' should be 'char dir[4][5+1];' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
buf = malloc(sizeof(format) + sizeof(args));
```

What is this supposed to do? `sizeof (format)` is just the size of a pointer, 4 bytes for 32-bit system or 8 bytes for 64-bit. `sizeof (args)` is just another name for `sizeof (va_list)`, which is an implementation-defined type. However, you are using this as the expected size of a string.

Likely you will overflow this buffer and run into undefined behavior.

It's always better to use the variants of `snprintf`, which take a specified output buffer size.

**Edit:** Additionally, as @Mahonri noticed, you have put the string `"North"` into an array with space for only 5 characters and this discarded the terminating NUL byte. This caused `sprintf` to overrun the intended end of the string. I would have expected it to print `NorthEast` instead, but it's still only undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. The malloc was simply my half-baked attempt to allocate some space for it. I'll review that statement presently.

Comment: I am not sure it is really UB. `dir[0]` and `dir[1]` are guaranteed to be contiguous, and as we know, `dir[1][4]` is `\0`. So I'd say it is guaranteed that `dir` is laid out as `"NorthEast\0SouthWest\0"` and so all mentioned string accesses are ok this way.

Comment: @glglgl And if you try to print `NorthEast and`, that already may overflow the buffer on a 32-bit system, leading to UB. Also the `NorthSouth` behavior is inexplicable by this theory.

Comment: @Potatoswatter You are right, the wrong allocation in `mprintf()` is indeed UB. I was referring to the array... The `NorthSouth` thing then can only explained with this.

Answer (score 0):

On recent enough systems, `snprintf()` tells you the number of bytes required even if it doesn't anything else. That makes your code as easy as

```
char* mprintfv(const char * format, va_list ap) {
    // This version should always be given for the case someone wants to build on it.

    va_list ap2;

    va_copy(ap2, ap);
    size_t length = vsprintf(NULL, format, ap2);
    va_end(ap2);
    if (size_t < 0) return NULL;
    char *buf = malloc(length + 1);
    if (!buf) return NULL;
    vsprintf(buf, format, ap2);
    return buf;
}

char* mprintf(const char * format, ...) {
    /* Prints a statement containing a format and then multiple arguments. */

    va_list args;

    va_start (args, format);
    char *buf = mprintfv(format, args);
    va_end(args);

    return buf;
}
```

On older systems, however, it might happen that `sprintf()` returns without telling how much space is needed. In this case, you'd have to create a loop which successively grows your memory block until it works, and resize it again.